# How to use and create a daemon thread and optimal utilization with Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a blackjack game for my high school programming class and I need a method that tracks card values and bets to run constantly in the background. Research on this website revealed that daemon threads are the answer. If this is not true, please provide me with a suitable alternative and include examples of how to use and create the alternative.

My problem is that I do not understand how to create a daemon thread. I would appreciate an explanation and an example of how to use and create a daemon thread.

There is just one more problem, for my program, I created a resource class that contains all the code for my dealer. The players are subclasses of the dealer and all are subclasses of JPanel. As I say in the subject, this blackjack game uses Swing to display the game and this is where the "optimal utilization" comes in. I have the application file in which the dealer and player objects are entered like so:

```
    public class PanelProject extends JPanel
{

   private PlayerBoxClubs PlayerOne;
   private PlayerBoxHearts PlayerTwo;  
   private PlayerBoxSpades PlayerThree;
   private DealerBoxDiamonds DealerOne;


   public PanelProject()

  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  JPanel CenterSub = new JPanel();
  CenterSub.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  add(CenterSub, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  PlayerOne = new PlayerBoxClubs();
  add(PlayerOne, BorderLayout.WEST);

  PlayerTwo = new PlayerBoxHearts();
  add(PlayerTwo, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  PlayerThree = new PlayerBoxSpades();
  add(PlayerThree, BorderLayout.EAST);   

  DealerOne = new DealerBoxDiamonds();
  add(DealerOne, BorderLayout.NORTH);

  JButton Quit = new JButton("Quit");
  Quit.addActionListener(new QuitListener());
  CenterSub.add(Quit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }
```

So, my second question is this: Where should I place the daemon thread, in the application file, in the dealer class (which is the superclass to the players) or somewhere else?

Comment: @assylias, don't just go around just editing people's questions as you see fit. Answer them as well. I need help with the question at hand, not with the structure thereof.

Comment: It is standard practice on Stackoverflow. See for example http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135619/is-it-correct-to-edit-question-to-remove-verbose-introduction - And the reason why I did not answer your question is that I did not completely understand what you want. For example, you mention a daemon thread but there is nothing related in the sample you provide (which by the way does not compile).

Comment: It doesn't compile because there is more code that is irrelevant nor do you have the code for the players or dealer. I understand that it may be standard practice, but I was concerned that my question would be marked as duplicate due to the presence of so many questions related to daemon threads. Thus I prefaced with that desire so that people would not chalk my question up as a duplicate and not answer it.

Comment: What I want is an explanation, complete with example(s), of how to create and use a daemon thread, if it is the solution to my issue. I also would like to know if the daemon thread should be in my superclass, each subclass, or in the application file. If you want, I can email you the entirety of my code so that you can understand my issue in depth.

Comment: @assylias, would you look at that, Moose Morals understood exactly what I needed without editing my post and whining about not understanding what I wanted. He also realized that he didn't need to compile any code to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // Do interesting background tasks, probably in a while(running) loop.
    }
});

// This next line is the answer to your question
t.setDaemon(true);

t.start();
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29)

The only difference between a regular thread and a daemon thread is that the JVM will happily exit if the only threads running are marked daemon.

Answering "Where to place it" is harder, as that depends on the structure you already have, and how much work you're going to do in the run() method. Broadly, the more work it does, the more likely it should be in its own file/class (the two are more or less the same thing in Java).

Comment: the code that goes into the run method tracks players' hand values and their bets. it determines when the players go bust, get blackjack, or if they lose. The structure is as such: DealerBox extends JPanel and is the superclass for the players such that PlayerBox1, PlayerBox2, PlayerBox3 extend DealerBox. I figure the best place for the thread is in the superclass but I am not sure.

Comment: ignore my comments... Just ignore them.

Comment: You can delete your comments (link on the right of the comment)